# mod_rewrite : only forward parameter that starts with number 4

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to modify the following rewrite conditions so that only strings that begin with the number 4 are redirected to the process.php page as a variable:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /process.php?variable=$1 [L]
```

So the following

```
http://www.domain.com/4shopping
```

will be mapped to

```
http://www.domain.com/process.php?variable=4shopping
```

But the following will not

```
http://www.domain.com/shopping
```

The reason for this is that /shopping is just a normal page (served by Wordpress), but /4shopping is a code that should map on to the /process.php as a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(4[^/]*)$ /process.php?variable=$1 [L]
```

The regular expression means:

```
^      Start of string
(      Start capturing group (for $1)
 4     A literal "4"
 [^/]* Any character except "/", 0 or more times
)      End capturing group
$      End of string
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation. If the 4 condition isn't met, do you know how to then to switch back to a secondary condition, which for Wordpress is:

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

I'm just getting errors if I run 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(4[^/]*)$ /process.php?variable=$1 [L]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

Comment: Sorry that was a bit hashed up. What I was trying to say is that I need something that says "if 4 exists then /process.php?variable=$1 [L], otherwise /index.php [L]